# Define different font size for text and line spacing and create an image from it using C#

Tags: c#, image, text

I know how to create an image from text in C# and how to specify a certain font size for the text.  But, I want to be able to have a few lines of text where the text is one font size - but the line spacing is a smaller font size - and be able to create an image from this in C#.

For example, I have three lines of text.  The font size for each text line is 24 (not sure what the unit is - pixels? point?).  But, I want the line spacing between each text line to only be 8.

Does anyone know how this can be accomplished?

Comment: What have you researched so far? Can you provide some code snippets for the logic that you are trying to implement?

Answer (score 2):

Try to draw each line separately and define its vertical position as vertical position of the previous line plus your desired spacing.

```
var left = 0;
var top = 0;
var myFontSize = 12;
var mySpacing = 8;

var myFont = new Font("MyFontFamily", myFontSize);
var myBrush = Brushes.Black;

var myLines = new List<string>{
    // your strings here
};

for(var i = 0; i < myLines.Count; i++)
{
    var lineText = myLines[i];

    // this line is needed to get line size in pixels, regardless in which units font size is specified
    // also different fonts can have different image sizes for the same font size
    var lineImageSize = graphics.MeasureString(lineText, myFont);

    graphics.DrawString(myLines[i], myFont, myBrush, left, top + (i * (lineImageSize.Height + mySpacing))); 
}
```